# Ruby on Rails scope test for current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a request table that `belongs_to :contact`

I want a scope statement in the request.rb file to test if the contact is the current user.

```
scope :myopen, where(:contact_id => current_user.id)
```

Returns:
undefined local variable or method `current_user'

What do I use for the current user id?

Thanks

Comment: The current user's id, but I think you need a lambda scope. Not sure, and can't delete this comment from mobile browser :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, nor should you. There is no "current" user at the database level.

You need to pass the user object in to a class-level method:

```
def self.open_for_user(user)
  where(:contact_id => user.id)
end
```

Comment: The requests are in a table called worequests.  I create a list in the view file by using "  <% @worequests.each do |worequest| %> "  Is there a way to use a sql stmt as part of the do statement instead of using a scope stmt in the controller?  I'm new to RoR and more used to using sql.